# Interfaces not working as expected in Entity framework generated partial classes

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4

I'm having a problem with a project I'm working on in Entity Framework 4.0, .NET 4.0.

I have gone down the model first route.

I've been creating my model and have just generated the partial classes by right clicking in my model designer and then clicking **Add Code Generation Item...**

I've then created some partial classes like so:

**EDIT**: These are all in the same namespace as the generated classes.

```
public partial class Foo : IFoo{
}

public partial class Bar : IBar{
}

public partial class SomethingElse : ISomethingElse{
}
```

I've looked at the generated entity framework code and **Foo** has the properties **Bar** and **SomethingElse** and they are the type generated by entity framework.

Here's how the interface for **IFoo** is set up:

```
public interface IFoo{

  IBar Bar {get; set;}
  ISomethingElse SomethingElse {get; set;}

}
```

**EDIT**: The interfaces are in a different class library to the entity framework classes.

My problem is that the compiler is complaining that Foo does not implement the interface IFoo.

I'm really confused as to what is happening.

If anyone could shed some light on this that would be great. I have a feeling I am just missing something.

Comment: Are you calling the interface from the same partial class that has the implementation?

Comment: Does the compiler say which of the properties aren't implemented? Would you mind posting a skeleton of your Foo class too? Is it possible that you're lacking a getter or a setter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand the problem is that class `Foo` has property with return type `Bar`, but you are asking to implement property with return type `IBar`. You can try to workaround it with explicit implementation:

```
public partial class Foo : IFoo
{
     IBar IFoo.Bar 
     {
        get { return ((Foo)this).Bar }
        set { ((Foo)this.Bar) = (Bar)value; }
     }    
}
```

Comment: I see, thank you for answering the question. Does anyone mind explaining to me as to why this happens?

Comment: I think I understand it now. Of course you can't set a property as the interface as obviously not every class/object that implements the same interface is the same object, the GET would work fine, but in order to set this property it would have to be the same type.